# How do I create multiple edit text with the activity instead of a database? Kotlin

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

How can I create an edit text row, I want them to appear in the layout, so it appears in the xml of the activity as it would? It doesn't matter if it is out of order, but I would like to be able to read all the EditText as well, taking into account that n_var of EditText will be created:

My activity .kt:

```
class RestrictionsActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_restrictions)
        var intent = getIntent()
        var min_max = intent.getBooleanExtra("min_max",true)
        var n_var = intent.getIntExtra("var",0) //n number of EditText

    }
}
```

My layout .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WriteProblem.RestrictionsActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_night_walk">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Funcion Objetivo"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/id_fo_input"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/min_or_max_input"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="012312"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/min_max_fo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/min_max_fo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/min_max_fo"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want it to be like that, no matter the design, I'll be doing it:
[image]

Comment: Could you please specify what exactly you want to achieve? You're passing one parameter `n_var` but the image shows 2 variables `x1` and `x2`. Do you want a method that takes 1 variable as a count & prints that amount of edit texts or 2/more variables?

Comment: @SaadAAkash that image is only from an app that has that functionality, it is not mine, that is why I uploaded it, however in this case as the image shows 3 EditText then the n_var is equivalent to 3, now I also need that have those *x (EditText number), if you don't let me understand, please keep asking me

Comment: You will have to create your Layout dynamically and add them to a container in Java

Comment: @Rafsanjani How would you do that, could you provide a tutorial or make me a simple java example as an answer? please